# Update all the existing email addresses to include the user's surname

Tags: email, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

We're a small company using Microsoft Office 365 for our company emails.

We're expanding, and would like to start using our full names in our email addresses, previously it was just first names.

eg./. john@example.com becomes john.smith@example.com

What's the best way to achieve this with minimum fuss?  Whilst making sure emails using the old address are still received, and our staff send emails with their "full name" address.

Comment: A PowerShell script should easily enable you to do that or an address policy.

Answer (score 1):

I use office 365 at the company I work for. I believe that there is an 'alias' setting in the account setup area where you can put in the first.last part.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/email/add-another-email-alias-for-a-user?view=o365-worldwide

You must have admin permissions to do this.

1. In the admin center, go to the Users > Active users page.
2. On the Active Users page, select the user > Manage email aliases. You won't see this option if the person doesn't have a license assigned to them.
3. Select + Add an alias and enter a new alias for the user.
4. When you're done, choose Save changes.
5. Wait 24 hours for the new aliases to populate throughout Office 365.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.